# Using Namespaces in Different Projects in C#

Tags: c#

I am confused on how to use a namespace. I understand that a namespace is a way to group a variety of different classes into one section. My problem is I don't understand how to use such a namespace.

For example lets say I create

```
using System;

namespace MyMath
{
     static class MyOperations
     {
           public static int MyAdd(int x, int y)
           {
                return x + y;
           }
     }
}
```

This is created in a seperate project in C#.

Now what if I want to use this namespace in a different project to use my method how do I go about doing that?

```
using System;
using MyMath;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             int sum = MyOperations.Add(5, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

This will give me an error. I don't understand where I put the Program.cs of the MyMath project to make it useable in the other project.

Comment: Check this out https://csharp-station.com/Tutorial/CSharp/Lesson06

Answer (score 2):

There are two things you have to do:

1. Add a reference to MyMath's dll.
2. The `MyOperations` class should have a `public` access modifier. Right now, it has `internal`; that means, you can use the class *only* in the same assembly it is declared in. Change it to the following: `public static class MyOperations`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a project reference in your console project to your class library project.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3st0d45.aspx?f=255&mspperror=-2147217396#Anchor_1

Answer (score 0):

You have two options. Suppose MyMath is a Main Namespace where you will add Test Namespace

If you use different project in same Solution Explorer then you need to add source project from Add Reference->Project then select.

If you use different project in different Solution Explorer then you need to add dll of Source(Test Namespace) project from Add Reference.

We can use Test Namespace

```
using Test;
```